# Windows Authentication with IIS 6.0 not working anymore

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

We had a Sharepoint site running on a server which was a domain controller and everything was working fine (IIS6), everyone could login using windows authentication. We've since added a new domain controller and demoted the IIS server to be a member server. Since then external users arent able to access the sharepoint site. The username/password prompt appears but it keeps re-appearing when credentials are entered. On the IIS server there are logs that show access denied (unknown username/password) against the connection attempt.

I think IIS is still trying to authenticate those users itself (rather than passing on on the request to the new domain controller).

Does anyone have any ideas how we could resolve this??

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, typically when you have an IIS server on a DC there are all sorts of stuff that goes wrong:

- [FrontPage](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.inetserver.iis&tid=7a3351a8-af7d-4d6c-9ab0-41cba7b12c79&cat=en&lang=en&cr=&sloc=en-us&m=1&p=1)
- [WSUS](http://forums.techarena.in/server-update-service/449129.htm)

What I would look at is that the IUSR account is infact the correct one, and *not* the domain one - you actually might not have an IUSR account since it would have been domain specific.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms955939.aspx) has some information regarding IIS on DC's, and this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300432) talks about promoting a member server to a DC.  Here are [details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179801.aspx) on the IUSR and IWAM accounts, which will probably have to be recreated and re-linked in the metabase.